# User disappeared from login screen

Tags: login-screen, username

I can not log in on the graphical login since my username does not appear as a possible choice. What dictates which users appear there?

I just changed my uid from 1000 to 872 while being logged in as root using `usermod`. All went smooth: entry in `/etc/passwd` was amended, file ownership in `/home/mysloginname` was changed. I can login on a text console and everything is fine. However the graphical display does not offer my username. What do I need to change?

Comment: Does this still persist after a reboot?

Comment: yes. Issue now solved with information provided by @steeldriver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using lightdm as your display manager, you can change the minimum displayed uid via the /etc/lightdm/users.conf file, e.g. to display all users with uids above 500

```
[UserAccounts]
minimum-uid=500
```

The default in Ubuntu is 1000, which is why your 872 user is not shown