# User does not appear on login

Tags: login, 20.04, users, fish

I just changed by default shell from bash to fish after a clean 20.04 install, and when I restarted afterwards my user does not appear at the login screen or in my settings.

I can still login if I select *not listed* and type in my user and password manually, and all programs are the same as before. I went wrong when editing `/etc/shells` or something, but I am not sure how to fix it as my user still exists, it just does not appear. I have edited the my users line on `/etc/passwd` to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if this helps or not: https://askubuntu.com/questions/324981/user-disappeared-from-login-screen

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix no it does not, there is a new display manager, GDM, after Ubuntu 16 which doesnt hold a similar file from what I have seen. Thank you though

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you still stuck with this issue (probably not) but I had the same problem yesterday and I found the solution for it on this post answer [Ubuntu 20.04 user not listed to login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1234452/ubuntu-20-04-user-not-listed-to-login).

Hope that could help you too.

Best regards.